# auto layout issue in landscape view custom keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, autolayout, landscape

i have create keyboard.xib for custom keyboard it working fine in portrait mode in all devices but i am unable to set constraint for landscape mode.

```
self.keyboard=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Keyboard" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self addGesturesToKeyboard];
self.inputView=self.keyboard;
```

[image]

[image]

someone tell me why this is happening, or what constraint i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use size-classes to build UI (in single xib)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html